# Bootstrap Carousel Not working and interfering with other jquery. Why is that?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, bootstrap-carousel

I have been trying for quite some time to figure out how to insert a bootstrap carousel with no luck. I don't know if it's bc of how I'm inserting the script. I downloaded bootstrap and put it into my folder. I'm following video after video and online tutorials with no luck. With what I have now, I see that somehow, the script is interfering with my nav, the drop down information that appears when you hover over the words are now separated, when they used to be directly under the word with no padding or margin between. I simply wish to have a carousel directly underneath my nav, while still allowing the nav to drop down with information when hovered over using the js I have already placed.

Here is my code. Can someone please help me understand what is going wrong and how to fix it?

my html is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html >
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Gender Identity 2</title>



      <link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">

</head>
<div class="container">
<header> 
  <img class="banner" src="images/banner.png"> 
  <div class="gender">
    <h3> Gender Identity </h3>
  </div>
</header>

<div id="wrap"> 

 <div id="tabwrap"> 
  <ul id="tabs">
   <li >
     <a href="#bacon" class="cyan">Terms</a>
   </li>

    <li>
     <a href="#batfish" class="green">Resources</a>
    </li> 

   <li>
     <a href="#tuna" class="lav">Culture</a>
    </li> 

    <li>
      <a href="#sausage" class="teal">Share</a>
    </li>

  </ul> 

  <div id="content"> 
    <div id="bacon" class="animated"> <p>Bacon ipsum dolor amet ribeye short loin leberkas andouille jerky meatloaf pork spare ribs corned beef. Andouille ham hock ground round, shankle pastrami rump hamburger filet mignon. </p></div>
    <div id="batfish" class="animated"><p>Batfish warmouth orbicular combtooth blenny; madtom, knifefish handfish rock beauty armorhead frogfish. Cownose ray pupfish pencilfish char fangtooth marblefish longfin dragonfish armored searobin hamlet.</p></div>
    <div id="tuna" class="animated"><p>Tuna, sculpin squeaker rice eel, lamprey triggerfish mooneye African glass catfish, loach wolf-eel yellowhead jawfish grass carp sea dragon neon tetra. Fingerfish forehead brooder sarcastic fringehead sixgill ray, scaly dragonfish bluntnose minnow.</p></div>
    <div id="sausage" class="animated"> <p>Sausage ground round sirloin ham hock t-bone tongue strip steak meatloaf landjaeger shankle andouille. Turducken doner brisket, shank salami shoulder kevin filet mignon ball tip chicken.</p> 
    </div> <!-- End of Div-->
   </div> <!-- End of Div-->
  </div><!-- End of Div-->

<!-- Carousel Code Start -->

<div id = "myCarousel" class = "carousel">

<ol class = "carousel-indicators">
<li data-target = "#myCarousel" data-slide-to = "0" class = "active"></li>
<li data-target = "#myCarousel" data-slide-to = "1"></li>
<li data-target = "#myCarousel" data-slide-to = "2"></li>
</ol>

<div class = "carousel-inner">

<div class = "item active">
<img src="http://placehold.it/1250x660" alt = "pic1" class = "img-responsive">
</div>


<div class = "item">
<img src="http://placehold.it/1250x660" alt = "pic1" class = "img-responsive">
</div>


<div class = "item">
<img src="http://placehold.it/1250x660" alt = "pic1" class = "img-responsive">
</div>

</div>

</div>

 <!-- <div class="main-caro">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/1250x660">

  </div> <!-- End of Div--> -->

<!-- Carousel Code End -->

</div> <!-- End of last Div-->

  <script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js'></script>
    <script src="js/index.js"></script>

<!--  Bootstrap -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


</body>
</html>
```

my css is:

```
@font-face { font-family: "aqua"; 
  src: url('aqua.ttf'); } 
@font-face { font-family: "axis"; 
  src: url('Axis Extrabold.otf'); } 
@font-face { font-family: "atami"; 
  src: url('Atami-Regular.otf'); } 



.container {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.banner{
  display: block;
margin: 0 auto;
  width: 100%;
  min-width: 400px;
}

.gender {
  padding-top: 20px;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
 /* background-color: black; */
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
.gender h3{
text-align: center;
 color: rgb(0,0,0); /* white*/
  animation: rgb infinite alternate;
  animation-duration: 15s;
  font-size: 2em;
}

@keyframes rgb {
  /* 0% will fallback to the default background-color of #rgb*/
 50% {color: rgb(29,185,226); /*blue*/ }
  75% {color: rgb(105,45,138); /*purple*/ }
  100% {color: rgb(237,49,147); /*pink*/}
}

h3{
font-family: "axis", sans-serif;
}

* { -moz-box-sizing: border-box; -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; box-sizing: border-box;  margin: 0; padding: 0; }

#wrap { width: 75%; margin: 0 auto; min-width: 300px; max-width: 1400px; }

#tabwrap {
    background: #fff;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 300px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    /*box-shadow: 0 0 20px #ddd;*/
    /*border: 1px solid #ddd;*/
}
#tabs { overflow: hidden;  }
#tabs li { list-style: none;
           font-family: "axis", sans-serif; }

#tabs li a {
    float: left;
    display: block;
    padding: 10px;
    color: black;
    width: 25%;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-align: center;
    /*border-right: 1px solid #555;
    border-left: 1px solid #888;*/
    font-size: 15px;

}

#tabs li a:hover { background: #666; }
#tabs li:first-child a { border-left: 0; }
#tabs li:last-child a { border-right: 0; }

#tabs li.current a {
    background: #fff;
    color: #666;

}

#tabs li.current a.cyan{
    background: rgb(245,166,200); /*pink*/
    color: white;
}

#tabs li.current a.green{
background-color: rgb(164,206,249); /*blue*/
    color: white;
}

#tabs li.current a.lav{
 background-color: rgb(200,200,255);
    color: white;
}


#tabs li.current a.teal{
 background-color: rgb(163,109,174);
    color: white;
}



#content > div {
    clear: both;
    padding: 20px;
    line-height: 19px;
    color: white;
    display: none;
font-family: "axis", sans-serif;

}
.animated {
    -webkit-animation-duration: 1s;
       -moz-animation-duration: 1s;
         -o-animation-duration: 1s;
            animation-duration: 2s;
}

#content .current { display: block }
#content p { margin: 0 0 20px 0;}

@-webkit-keyframes fadeInLeft {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transform: translateX(-10px);
    transform: translateX(-10px);
  }

  100% {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transform: translateX(0);
    transform: translateX(0);
  }
}

@keyframes fadeInLeft {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transform: translateX(-10px);
    -ms-transform: translateX(-10px);
    transform: translateX(-10px);
  }

  100% {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transform: translateX(0);
    -ms-transform: translateX(0);
    transform: translateX(0);
  }
}

.fadeInLeft {
  -webkit-animation-name: fadeInLeft;
  animation-name: fadeInLeft;
}

#bacon {
  background-color: rgb(245,166,200); /*pink*/
}

#batfish {
  background-color: rgb(164,206,249); /*blue*/
}

#tuna {
    background-color: rgb(200,200,255);
}

#sausage {
    background-color: rgb(163,109,174);
  z-index: 1;
}

.main-caro img{
  display:block;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-top: -215px;
padding-top: 20px;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
  z-index:-1;
}
```

and my js is:

```
$('#tabs li a').hover(function(e) {
    $('#tabs li, #content .current').removeClass('current').removeClass('fadeInLeft'); 
    $(this).parent().addClass('current');
    var currentTab = $(this).attr('href');
    $(currentTab).addClass('current fadeInLeft');
    e.preventDefault();

}, function(){
   $('#tabs li, #content .current').removeClass('current').removeClass('fadeInLeft');
});
```

Again, I have downloaded bootstrap and inserted it into my main folder as it's own folder named bootstrap, where the css folder and js folder are then found.

Thank you for any assistance given!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for the separation between the menu links you hover over and the hover box that appears is a style rule from bootstrap.min.css

```
ol, ul {
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    margin-top: 0px;
}
```

to make your tabs ul have 0px margin bottom add this to your style.css:

```
ul#tabs {
    margin-bottom: 0px;
}
```

I'm not sure why the carousel is not working for you. It works for me. Maybe it is working but because all the images are the same it doesn't look like it?

Here is a [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/G3RjtmSBAXqZ5vuc3D30?p=preview) with the extra space issue fixed.

EDIT (adding solution to carousel issue):

change

```
<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel">
```

to

```
<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide">
```

and if you want the carousel to cycle automatically you need to add

```
$(function() {
    $('.carousel').carousel();
});
```

to your javascript.

Comment: Thank you for the help with the nav! I appreciate it a lot. Another question: Is the bootstrap css also causing the carousel to be so far away from the nav? There seems to be a large amount of padding between the two. I would like the nav to be directly above the slider, with maybe 40 pxs of space between them. If that makes sense?

Comment: The extra space between nav and carousel is from one of your custom style rules: #tabwrap { min-height: 300px; } so just remove that min-height and add padding-bottom: 40px;

Comment: And before you ask, to make the hover box appear on top of the carousel instead of pushing it down, add style rule: #content { position: absolute; z-index: 1; }

Comment: Thank you very much for all that information. But I just have one last question. Now everything works as you say, however, my nav is not responsive, going off the screen as I scale the page and when on mobile. How can this be fixed?

Comment: That's not a question with a simple answer. To do it manually, start by googling "css media query". You might also want to have a look at https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/layout/responsive-utilities/ if you want to do it the bootstrap way.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried adding a noConflict to the jQuery library that loads last? I've had a similar issue where my carousel worked alone, but as soon as I added it to a page that already used a jQuery library, it turned out that the libraries didn't mesh well.

Your code is loading two jQuery libraries.

```
    <script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js'></script>
```

then

```
   <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

I'm betting it needs a noConflict added.

[jQuery.noConflict()](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.noconflict/)